# Change file name and display without change original name

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5

I'am new to asp.net and recently working on a project. I have saved file name in database with a changed name.Its something like

> **682c3494-2c16-4de6-bc30-c4c4ab624d7c_Penguins.jpg**

. When I send this to view it's display the whole name. Thing I need to do is remove the string before "_" and display it like

> **Penguins.jpg**

but I don't know how to do this.

In controller I read database record like this

```
var attachment = db.Attachment.Where(z => z.AttachmentID == id).ToList();
```

In my view page I simply display it like this

```
@item.DocumentName
```

I have no idea how to remove previous part from file name and send it to view.
Is there anyone who can help me I appreciate it very much

Comment: if you have only one "_" you can use IndexOf() for string and use Substring() to extract required part.

Comment: So you want to remove remove all the text in front of `_` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [String.Substring](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.substring%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method to remove the `682c3494-2c16-4de6-bc30-c4c4ab624d7c_`.

For Example:

```
@item.DocumentName.Substring(37) // 37 is the length of string from first char to _
```

Comment: Thanks for your help.This is the easiest way I found. Until my file name before _ 36 it's working :)

Answer (score 2):

A solution using `IndexOf()` and `Substring()`. you can use this if you have file names with same file name format of `A character seqience` + `_` + `actual file name`

```
String fname = "682c3494-2c16-4de6-bc30-c4c4ab624d7c_Penguins.jpg"; // item.DocumentName can be used here

int index = fname.IndexOf("_"); // getting index of "_" 

String extracted = fname.Substring(index+1); // Extracting actual file name
```